# Non-drive bottom bracket cup loose/wobbly - what options are there?

Tags: bottom-bracket

I have this pretty/ugly Pinarello single speed and for a while I had a problem with the bottom bracket lockring loosening up and the BB clicking.

After I removed the cranks and the lockring I can feel that the non-drive side BB cup is not tight in the BB thread. I really mean the cup, not the spindle. 
Even when the cup is fully screwed in (so the spindle turns freely but doesn't have any wobbles) I can move the non-drive cup up/down/left/right by hand. It's a tiny movement, but it's observable and visible to a naked eye. It's as the threads on the cup and the BB did not match. The threads on the cup and inside the BB look ok, but I haven't cleaned them yet.

If I put locking on the removed cup it also isn't tight. It seems it fits, but there is tiny sideways movement.

(I don't think this related but after removing the non-drive side cup I still cannot remove the spindle - which I think usually should come out.)

Question:
What are my options? Since the non-drive side cup for cartridge BBs are typically made of plastic, could this be an option?

[image]
The two pictures below are my attempt to show that the cup can move up/down:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This bottom bracket has been showing up so much that replacing it would probably be the best option.

Comment: @ojs Heh, this is just the 2nd question and it is about replacing it - I just wonder what the best replacement would be.

Comment: I guess the first one has been edited and bumped to front page so much that I thought it was many different questions. Anyways, a cartridge BB should solve the problem, but it sounds like the lock ring is too loose. With Italian BBs threadlocker is also a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the same bike as [Bottom bracket lockring keeps loosening up](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/43418/bottom-bracket-lockring-keeps-loosening-up)  ?   Colour looks the same.

It is time for a new BB cartridge I think, and if that doesn't fix it, then the BB threads are damaged and the frame is scrap.

Comment: Fair advice. I'm not trying to avoid changing the cup/BB. I just don't know if I should try a cartridge BB since it would have a plastic cup, that isn't so important (is it?) or go with a new cup for the existing cup/cone...

Comment: the Shimano bb-un26 has a plastic cup but I believe the next one up, bb-un55, has 2 metal cups. I don't feel that it should be a concern either way although the un55 is definitely higher quality

Answer (score 1):

Is this a bottom bracket that you know the origins of? it is possible that this is an English bottom bracket cup (1.37in ≈ 34.79mm) rather than an Italian one (36mm ≈ 1.41in) if the frame is Italian thread.

If the problem is ultimately the threads, I would try some Teflon tape or thread locker (blue) before I scrapped the whole thing. If you really, really love the frame, there are some companies that make 'compression fit' bottom brackets that don't use the threads (I believe Phil wood makes a very expensive one).